# Annotation that "steals" parameter from the method it's annotating and processes it

Tags: java

I'm trying to create an authentication system for a project I'm working on. I have a user system working with sessions (and session IDs). For authentication, I've created a method that takes a session ID, checks it against a map with sessionID - username entries and throws an exception if the session ID isn't in there.
The problem is in calling the method. I could just do it the hard way and manually calling the method in every other method in the entire project but I was wondering if there's a better way to do this. Could someone create a method annotation that "steals" the first parameter of its method (the first parameter being the session ID), authenticates it (using the authentication method) and if everything's correct calls the method that was about to be called?

Example:

The method to be invoked

```java
@Authenticate
public AtlasResult addBook(BookModel model) {
    // Some logic here...
}
```

The actual invoking of the method:

```java
String sessionId = "123";
BookManager.addBook(sessionId, new BookModel());
```

The expected results should be:
The `addBook` method is invoked with 2 parameters -> the `@Authenticate` annotation takes the first parameter and checks it -> the session ID is validated -> the `addBook` is invoked with only 1 parameter (the book model).

Answer (score 2):

Ideal way would be to get session identifier in header and put logic in filter.

For your case, since you want to read that value from method param. Method param could be dynamic and the position can also change.

Try below code, which will get hold of value passed to the method param and you can validate session based on value passed to the method param annotated with custom annotation we are going to create-

1. You need to create an annotation which can be used to mark parameters passed to methods needs to be validated for session id check. This will tell which method param needs to be checked.

   ```
   package com.somePackage;

    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
    import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
    import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;
    import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
    import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
    import java.lang.annotation.Target;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
    @Documented
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Target({TYPE, FIELD, PARAMETER})
    public @interface ValidateSession{

    }
   ```
2. You need to write one advice logic which can be used to inspect value in params associated with the annotation, i.e the value passed to method params on which you have put the newly created annotation.The method has to be public since AOP will not be able to create proxy with private methods.

   ```
     package com.somepackage;


    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
    import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.reflect.MethodSignature;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;


    import java.lang.annotation.Annotation;
    import java.util.Objects;

    @Aspect
    public class ValidateSessionAdvice {

        @Autowired
        SomeServicetoCheckSession someService;

        private final static String POINTCUT_METHOD_PARAM_SESSION_CHECK = 
      "execution(* *(@ValidateSession (*), ..)) ||execution(* *(.., 
      @ValidateSession (*), ..)) || execution(* *(.., @ValidateSession (*)))";

        @Around(POINTCUT_METHOD_PARAM_SESSION_CHECK)
        public Object checkRequiredRequestBody(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) 
       throws Throwable {

            if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(key)) {
                MethodSignature methodSig = (MethodSignature) 
       joinPoint.getSignature();
                Annotation[][] annotations = 
      methodSig.getMethod().getParameterAnnotations();
                Object[] args = joinPoint.getArgs();
                for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotations[i]) {
                        if (ValidateSession.class.isInstance(annotation)) {
                            args[i] = checkValidSession(args[i].toString(), key);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return joinPoint.proceed(args);
            }
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        }


        private String checkValidSession(String value, String key) {
            if(someService.someMethod(value, key));
             return value;

             else throw SomeRuntimeException()
        }
    }
   ```

Usage inside contollers -

```
@PostMapping("/someendpoint/somepath/{someID}")
public ResponseEntity updateSomething(@ValidateSession @RequestParam String someValue, 
ValidateSession @PathVariable String someID)
        throws Exception {

}
```

Comment: Hey, I'm really thankful for the elaborate response and would love to try it but the school project I'm working on Is strictly on JavaFX, Hibernate and modules from maven (excluding spring framework, the project must be a native application unfortunately). Do you have knowledge of how this might be achieved without using spring?

Comment: How are you getting sessionId from the request?

Comment: It's returned from the login method and then kept in the controller (not yet implemented but i think that would be the general idea)

Comment: May be you can store the sessionId in some kind of persistence, say a DB or Cache when you create it. Since you will be returning the session Id in response to UI,  then expect it to be returned in some header from the UI. This header can be read filter, which will be executed before your controller and have all the details about request payload and header. This way, you can keep it at one place and use across different controllers.